# Firefox tooltip cut off with long 'title'

Tags: html, firefox, tooltip

In Firefox 62.0.3 if I have a long 'title' attribute on an element then the resulting tooltip doesn't show the whole text and looks like it is cut off (note the missing right-hand border line):

[image: screenshot of the title tooltip being cut off]

Googling the issue shows a couple open Firefox bugs that sound similar but have since been fixed.

Am I looking at a bug? Is there a workaround?

Comment: What's your local text size set to on your machine? Maybe it's a display setting problem.

Comment: @JacobH Firefox settings say Default font (Times New Roman) at size 16. I don't think I've ever changed it and it looks similar to the default of Chrome and Internet Explorer 11 as far as I can tell.

Comment: I mean the actual computer display. I think it's under display settings.

Comment: @JacobH it's set to "Smaller - 100% (default)"